# Colloquial translation of "increase in price"

Tags: translation, vocabulary

What is the common used colloquial translation of "increase in price"?

I know some of them like:

- 涨价
- 提价
- 价格上涨

Which one do you often use? or if there is better alternative, please let me know.

Comment: Thanks all for the answers. It's very hard to pick one from all answers here, all are good. I hope none are disappointed with my choice :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often use 漲价!

But I think the first and third one is really common.

For example, if you say "the price of the food is increasing this year".

It's equal to "食物今年又漲价了！" and "食物今年价格上漲了"

Answer (score 2):

涨价 most colloquial; often used as a descriptive word.

提价 colloquial, can be both a descriptive word and a verb.

价格上涨 formal, descriptive, used by news agencies.

Answer (score 1):

For reference in Southeast Asia people usually say

> 起价  (:
>   价钱又起啦~

Comment: 写着简体字，是新加坡，马来西亚？